# Using Stripe Connect, is it possible to create a charge using a new card, and then add the card to the customer

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm using Stripe Connect to create charges to customers, and right now I need to add the new card to the customer, and then create the charge.

I'm trying to optimize the process for creating a charge, and I want to see if it's possible to avoid adding the card to the customer until after the charge is created. That way I can return a response right after creating the charge, and add the card to the customer in a background job.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible: if you use the card token directly to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge), the token will be consumed and no longer usable to [create a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).

That said, when you use a token to create a customer, Stripe validates the card with the issuing bank. If the validation fails, then the request will fail and no customer will be created.

It is still possible for a card to be valid but for the charge to be declined (for example, if the card does not have enough funds for the charge you're trying to create), but if you were able to use the token to create a customer, there's a good chance that the charge will succeed.